# Num doenst work in my javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my JQuery script does the parseFloat is not working.

For example when the price is 1, the qty is 1 but when i add the percent in stead of 1.21 it show 10.21.

```
function update_price() {
    var row = $(this).parents('.item-row');
    var row = $(this).parents('.item-row');
    var price = row.find('.cost').val();
    var qty = row.find('.qty').val();
    var Bedrag = parseFloat(price * qty);
    var percentage = parseInt($('.btw').val());
    var BtwPercentage = parseFloat(Bedrag * (percentage / 100));
    var InclBtw = parseFloat(price + BtwPercentage);
    isNaN(price) ? row.find('.price').html("N/A") : row.find('.price').html("" + InclBtw);
}
```

Comment: `price` is a string, so `price + BtwPercentage` will be a string-concatenation, before `parseFloat` can take over.

Comment: Thanks Yoshi and Cerbrus its works:)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, ensure all operand types **before** using them in calculations. E.g. don't use `parseFloat` when doing math, instead use it when accessing the values: `var price = parseFloat(row.find('.cost').val());`

Comment: Tanks for the explanation but what if i have a second row and the tax is 6%? because know it will get the first entered tax

Comment: I think that deserves a new question, which should also include all relevant html as well.

Answer (score 4):

Replace:

```
var InclBtw = parseFloat(price + BtwPercentage);
```

With:

```
var InclBtw = parseFloat(price) + parseFloat(BtwPercentage);
```

Otherwise, you're trying to `parseFloat` on `string + string`

Answer (score 2):

You combine strings and numbers, and you should parse it always. 
You don't see types but javascript is strongly typed.
So I would parse even price and qty like so:

```
   function update_price() {
        var row = $(this).parents('.item-row');
        var price = parseFloat(row.find('.cost').val());
        var qty = parseFloat(row.find('.qty').val());
        var Bedrag = parseFloat(price * qty);
        var percentage = parseInt($('.btw').val());
        var BtwPercentage = parseFloat(Bedrag * (percentage / 100));
        var InclBtw = parseFloat(price + BtwPercentage);
        isNaN(price) ? row.find('.price').html("N/A") : row.find('.price').html("" + InclBtw);
    }
```

Comment: You should also include an explanation of what you changed and why. A snippet alone, especially when most of it is the same, isn't always easy to understand.